# Poor FPS on Minecraft with RX 570

Tags: memory, graphics-card, cpu, performance, java

I've looked around many forums, and most of them blame poor FPS in Minecraft due to a weak processor.

I get around 90-120FPS on Minecraft, which isn't really a huge complaint, but occasionally it will dip below 75, which is noticeable to me with my refresh rate of 75hz. While gaming, it's pretty easy to tell once your FPS has gone below your refresh rate, as the display becomes choppier and depending how low it's dropped, mouse movement feels slow.

The main thing that is bugging me is the fact that my laptop (i7 6500U & GT 940M) was able to achieve the same framerate. In other games though, there is a HUGE difference in framerates between the two machines.

I really want to blame the card here, but I really don't know if that's the issue. People have tested the game with a GTX 1050 and the same processor, and are nearly doubling my framerates.

So, my question is, what are some of the possible issues that could be causing Minecraft to run at such a low framerate? I've looked through Radeon Settings and a few forums, but I've had no luck in finding a solution.

Additional information:

I attempted allocating 2, 3, and 4 GB of RAM to Minecraft. No difference each time.

Videos show the same processor paired with a GTX 1050 are able to achieve framerates of 500. While I don't need it to be this high, I find it pretty odd my RX 570 can't get the same FPS at the very least.

I attempted making a profile for Minecraft in AMD Radeon Settings. I added the java within the Minecraft folder and the java outside of it. No luck.

Another video shows an i3-6100 on integrated graphics getting around the same FPS as me. I understand Minecraft is mostly CPU intensive, but I find it weird that it's almost like my graphics card isn't there.

I used ClockBlocker to ensure that it wasn't being downclocked, but nothing changed still.

Thanks in advance. I had to repost this here because I accidentally made my original post on a guest account. :/ Don't know if that isn't allowed or not, but sorry if it is.

SPECS: 
CPU: i3-6100

RAM: 2x4GB

MOTHERBOARD: Gigabyte ga-h110m-a

GPU: Radeon RX 570

PSU: 500W

HDD: 1TB

Comment: You have comments on your other question which you still have addressed

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. To answer your question, I have 8GB of RAM, and I've added my complete specs to the post.

Comment: How much memory is allowed to the Java virtual machine?  If you don't understand question, it means you should do some research, on Java performance best practices

Comment: Isn't this done using JVM args, such as -Xmx and -Xms? I said above that I attempted allocating 2-4GB without luck. Is there a different concept that you are referring to?

Answer (score 0):

If you're saying Minecraft is CPU-intensive, and you laptop with a core i7 gets higher framerate, then up to a core i5 because the desktop i5 is better then the laptop i7, because after all desktop components are higher that a higher tier laptop equivalent, and up your ram, because 8 gb isn't enough.